# ObjectAnimator's translationY on a ListView flickers

Tags: android, listview, animation, objectanimator

I am trying to move the ListVies's Y axis based on the scroll position on that ListView. To change the Y position I am translating using a `ObjectAnimator` which is set on a `setOnScrollListener`

Here is the function that gets called in `onScroll` event -

```
ObjectAnimator mover1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(postCommentsListView, "translationY",  - currentScrollPositionY);
mover1.setDuration(0);
mover1.start();
```

The problem is when I scroll very slowly, the translation flickers. But on a relatively fast scroll everything works fine.

Comment: setDuration(0) ? it has little sense to set duration to zero, you will see no animation so why to use an Animator at all?

Comment: You are right, this is more for the purpose of changing the position of the ListView than animation. I have tried `ListView.setTop(Y)`, it has some similar complications because of which I couldn't use it.